# Vue.Js cant set value of input type range

Tags: laravel, vue.js

For the life of me I cannot figure out why I can't set the value of the input range. When it is rendered, the "value" attribute just isn't there, and the browser defaults the value to 50..

```
@import "~@coreui/coreui/scss/coreui";

<template>
    <div :class="'form-group ' + s_class">
        <label for="formControlRange">{{title}}</label><span style="float:right;" id="holder"><span id="value">({{ def }})</span> {{unit}}</span>
        <input type="range"  :name="input_name" :min="min" :max="max" :value="def" oninput="$(this).closest('.form-group').children('#holder').children('#value').html('('+$(this).val()+')');" class="form-control-range" :id="input_name">
        <span style="float:left">{{min}} {{unit}}</span><span style="float:right">{{max}} {{unit}}</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        min:{type: String, required:true},
        max:{type: String, required:true},
        def:{type: String, required:true},
        title:{type: String, required:true},
        input_name:{type: String, required:true},
        unit:{type: String, required:false},
        s_class:{type: String, require:false}
    }
}

</script>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Thanks maxshuty, this was what I did but it still defaults the value to 50.

```
@import "~@coreui/coreui/scss/coreui";

<template>
    <div :class="'form-group ' + s_class">
        <label for="formControlRange">{{title}}</label><span style="float:right;" id="holder">({{value_model}}) {{unit}}</span>
        <input type="range" :name="input_name" :min="min" :max="max" v-model="value_model" class="form-control-range" :id="input_name">
        <span style="float:left">{{min}} {{unit}}</span><span style="float:right">{{max}} {{unit}}</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        min:{type: String, required:true},
        max:{type: String, required:true},
        def:{type: Number, required:true},
        title:{type: String, required:true},
        input_name:{type: String, required:true},
        unit:{type: String, required:false},
        s_class:{type: String, require:false}
    }, data: {
        value_model: 0
    }, created: function(){
        this.value_model = this.def
    }
}

</script>
```

Just for reference, this is how the value is being passed in so far: (In Laravel Blade)

```
<inputslider min="{{$input7['min']}}" max="{{$input7['max']}}" v-bind:def="{{$input7['value']}}" title="{{$input7['title']}}" input_name="{{$input7['name']}}"></inputslider>
```

Comment: try to use v-model

Comment: why are you using `oninput` use `@input` or `v-on` also `def` is of type string read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range

Comment: @RajkumarG Hello, I've changed it to number and passed the prop through v-bind, but it is still the same.
For the oninput, that one is jquery code, not vuejs. There are better ways to do this in vuejs but for the time being it works so i'm leaving it as is

Comment: @Kusy Unless I'm doing something wrong, I've tried using model but it ends up in the same result.

Comment: @AmosNg  
```
data: {
        value_model: 0
    },
```
is wrong 
data should return a new instance something like
```
data() {
return {
field1: 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your `data` values set wrong - it looks like many of them should not be `String` and should be `Number`.

Additionally I would bind it to a `v-model`. Finally, `oninput` has a bunch of jQuery it looks like that could be causing you issues. I wouldn't be mixing Vue and jQuery like that.

Here is a demo of your code (I removed all of the stuff we don't need from your post to answer this question):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.wrapper',
   data() {
      return {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        def: 50
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="range"  :min="min" :max="max" v-model="def" />
  Current Value: <span v-text="def"></span>
</div>
```

Finally here is your same code working (I migrated all of your `props` to be `data` in my example so that I could set their values):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '.wrapper',
   data() {
      return {
        value_model: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: 'Your title',
        input_name: 'My input',
        unit: 'Unit',
        s_class: 's-class'
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
          <label for="formControlRange">{{title}}</label><span style="float:right;" id="holder">({{value_model}}) {{unit}}</span>
        <input type="range" :name="input_name" :min="min" :max="max" v-model="value_model" class="form-control-range" :id="input_name">
        <span style="float:left">{{min}} {{unit}}</span><span style="float:right">{{max}} {{unit}}</span>
</div>
```

As a side note I would consider some better naming strategies for your values as things like `value_model` are very generic.

Comment: Hello, tried your method, edited my code (you can see the post above) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AmosNg because you still have `min` and `max` set to `String`. One minute I'll update my post for you

Comment: @AmosNg you still have some syntax issues but I have updated my answer to also include your exact code but fixed and working.

Comment: It seems I can't get your code working with the prop values. Any idea how to?

Comment: @AmosNg set your `data()` values to be your prop... for example if in your props you have `min` and your data you can use `minRange: this.min` as mutating props directly is considered an anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is not returning a new instance when something changes in your application.

You have

```
data: {
        value_model: 0
    }
```

Which should have been

```
data() {
   return {
      value_model: 0
   }
}

Check this https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html#data-2
```